# Override Console Close

Tags: c#, console, overriding

I know the GUI has

```
private void Form1_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.EventArgs e)
{
  //do stuff
}
```

But how can i do the same thing in a console application?

C#/.NET3.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how:

```
// Declare the SetConsoleCtrlHandler function
// as external and receiving a delegate.
[DllImport("Kernel32")]
public static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(HandlerRoutine Handler, bool Add);

// A delegate type to be used as the handler routine
// for SetConsoleCtrlHandler.
public delegate bool HandlerRoutine(CtrlTypes CtrlType);

// An enumerated type for the control messages
// sent to the handler routine.
public enum CtrlTypes
{
    CTRL_C_EVENT = 0,
    CTRL_BREAK_EVENT,
    CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT,
    CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT = 5,
    CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT
}

private static bool ConsoleCtrlCheck(CtrlTypes ctrlType)
{
    // Put your own handler here
    return true;
}

...

SetConsoleCtrlHandler(new HandlerRoutine(ConsoleCtrlCheck), true);
```

Comment: Where can i read more about this? I dont fully understand how to use it.

Comment: Read about P/Invoke (or PInvoke) on MSDN. Docs on SetConsoleCtrlHandler() are over there as well.

Comment: Ok, so I have a little more of an understanding, but i still don't know how to block the CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT, ive tried returning false/true if it catches that event, but no success.